# Kubectl how to connect to config file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I've setup a K8s cluster and got the config file which I have placed in the 
username/.kube directory

I can't seem to workout how to link my Powershell Kubectl to this config file by default. For instance if I try and run the following command I don't get the cluster I've setup.

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

If however, I run the following command, I do get a list of my current nodes

```
kubectl --kubeconfig="cluster-kubeconfig.yaml" get nodes
```

Comment: It seems your `...username/.kube/config` file is not configured in proper way. Better if you provide the contents of both of the files `...username/.kube/config` and `cluster-kubeconfig.yaml`. Be aware of printing the credentials of the cluster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy contents of `cluster-kubeconfig.yaml` file to `$HOME/.kube/config`

This will be the default kubernetes context file.

You can also override and point to any other custom kubernetes context using

```
 $Env:KUBECONFIG=("/path/to/cluster-kubeconfig.yaml")
```

as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#windows-powershell-1).

For more info check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/) out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the override method resolved it :-). The first method didn't seem to work for me.